# Pandas-Spotify API Slow Iteration

Tags: python, pandas, api, spotipy

I am working on extracting the audio features of millions of songs from Spotify's public API using the Spotipy Python library and the for loop I am using is taking WAY too long. I am taking the song URIs from a database table I have already created and am using a query to get a list of the URIs: here's a code snippet:
results = pd.read_sql("SELECT track_uri FROM dim_tracks ORDER BY track_uri)
results = pd.Series(results)

```
`output_df = pd.DataFrame()
for row in tqdm(results[0:20000]):
      output = pd.DataFrame(sp.audio_features(row))
      output_df = pd.concat([output_df, output])
output_df`
```

This example batch of 20,000 songs takes approx. 35 minutes to run. Is there a more efficient way to extract the audio features in this format?

I was previously using the Pandas append method and changed to the concat method and the runtime went down by 5 minutes. This is the most effective and efficient way I have found thus far.

Comment: i think you should share  what **sp.audio_features()** is doing.

Comment: sp is the alias for the Spotipy library. the audio_features function extracts the various audio features of a track (e.g., instrumentalness, energy, acousticness) using the connection I built to the Spotify API. It returns the result in JSON format but Pandas interprets the values as a dictionary

Comment: Yes, generally concat is faster than append. If I understand correctly you are making a get request for the results. How quickly the responses are returned from the other side depends entirely on the quality of the api service(here: spotify_api) you are using. I don't think you can speed up your code any more under these circumstances.